# The store or A store

Tags: articles

Do we say 'the store' or 'a store' to mean any store? For example:

1. In my opinion a gift bought from **the/a** store can never be as special as one made personally by the person giving it.
2. You have to pick them up from **the/a** store.

Answer (score 1):

Should the person you are talking to know which store or which kind of store you are talking about?  If so, use *the*.

Otherwise, use *a*.

Comment: I was answering an IELTS question. This was the question- "How people feel when they receive a home made gift and when they receive a shop bought gift." I used 'the' as you can see in the post.

Comment: In your example, there is no "which store" that the listener/reader needs to know about, so you would use *a*, not *the*.

Comment: You can sometimes use *the store* without the listener knowing which one you mean, but it's implied you're going somewhere specific (usually a grocery or convenience store). But in this case it's about stores in general, the idea of buying a gift at a store vs making one yourself - so *a store* feels better to me in this situation. That said, people who say *the store* might use it in this situation too! But if it's a test question, *a* is the safer bet.

Comment: *The* means the speaker is expecting the listener to know which X -- and X can be something nonspecific but the key is that the speaker expects X to be something mutually understood.  If there is only one store in the neighboorhood for example and two people from the same neighboorhood are talking, *the store* might be the tendency.

Comment: The sentence you quote refers to _a gift. Shop bought_ is a phrase describing the gift.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I don't understand your comment.

Comment: In the phrase 'when they receive a shop bought gift', the indefinite article applies to _gift_, not to _shop_.